# ListBox custom EditingControl

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I try to create a custom EditingControl for a ListBox in c#.

[image]

I am only want to change the square into a simple stripe. I make a lot of research but I don't find any solution. All stuff I found was about custom ListBoxes itself but not the EditingControl.

So, is there a way to capture the Paint-Event while entering the Control, or Overwriting some base-Class?

[image]

It should look something like this but you see, the default EditingControl make it a lil complex.

Greetings, Martin.

Comment: the difference between "what i have" and "what i want" is the grey  background of selected value . Clarify please, what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: is this web based or winforms or wpf or silverlight? I guess look into styling listboxitem

Comment: Hey Guys, first I want to modify the EditingControl from a white Box to a red Stripe, the grey Background dosnt matter so much. Secound the ListBox is a Control of the class System.Windows.Controls (.NET Framework)

Comment: do you mean ListBox or ListView ???? which control are you using in your code ? or doesn't matter , you just want to get a dropdown box with editable element having red background

Comment: I'am so freakn dump. So sorry, it is a ListView Control (public class ListView : Control). In result it it is a List, permanently seen with drag drop, adding items, delete items (and so on) functions. And the EditingControl should be a simple stripe, so the problem is to get this EditingControl and handle there Paint events.

Comment: looks like you use custom ListView implementation. the basic one , common ListView doesn't allow add or remove items in runtime.  can you post code